# Questionable Positioning of drawn Lines in Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have some question regarding HTML 5 Canvas and I hope you can help me to clear them.

Situation:
I have a canvas and some absolute positioned divs which are children of a relative positioned div.

```
<div class="relativeposition">
    <canvas id="drawarea" height="700" width="800"></canvas>
    <div id="absoluteposition1"></div>
    <div id="absoluteposition2"></div>
    <div id="absoluteposition3"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

So you can see the canvas and on the canvas there are the 3 different divs. Now I want to draw a polygon under every div in an each loop. The position of this polygon should almost be centered under the div. Under every div this position should be equal to the others divs.
[image]

The red caros are the positioned divs and just imagine that they are at the same position under every div. The Pseudo Code for drawing these caros is the following:

```
$.each(absolutepositionedDivs, function(index, value) {
    var divtop = absolutepositionedDiv.position().top;
    var divleft = absolutepositionedDiv.position().left;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(playerLeft + 76, playerTop + 154);
    context.lineTo(playerLeft + 46, playerTop + 174);
    context.lineTo(playerLeft + 55, playerTop + 190);
    context.lineTo(playerLeft + 97, playerTop + 190);
    context.lineTo(playerLeft + 106, playerTop + 174);
    context.lineTo(playerLeft + 76, playerTop + 154);
    context.closePath();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.stroke();
});
```

The initialization of canvas and so isn't in the code but I wrote it and it worked. Just ignore that the outcome of the draw isn't a caro...So the problem now is that the drawn objects aren't in an equal position as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

So I don't understand why every drawn object has a different position, even when I wrote that they all start from the same position of their div but end up in a different. Can you tell me why this is happening or have a solution do position all drawn polygons in the same position under their div?

EDIT: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/asfga/yjjhqpyL/

Comment: The red diamonds look like they are scaled and do not match the code you have given. You will have to provide more information.  From what I can see each diamond is rendered with s different scale and that would explain why they are all offset differently

Comment: Why different scale? The drawing in the each loop results in same diamonds but only at different positions or do I see it wrong?

Comment: The two images you have supplied that have diamonds show each diamond as different. You need to supply accurate information, including the CSS/HTML and the actual code or we can only guess at what the problem is. There is nothing wrong with the canvas rendering it will render at the correct pixel address every time. The problem is not the canvas but a setup problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response. I will update css settings tomorrow. Hope it will be clearer then for you

Comment: Updated it and created a fiddle. Some of the drawing isn't at the right position, hope you can help me ;)

Comment: Can't somebody help me by my problem? :/

Comment: Come on guys :(

Comment: I had a look at your fiddle. You need to make sure everything is lined up. Use element.getBoundingClientRect() to get the position of elements. Use that to workout where on the canvas you need to draw. It has top,left,bottom,right, width and height. First the canvas then the divs that you are wanting to draw over. Subtract the canvas top left from each div top left to get the pix pos of each div. then use width and height of the div to get the correct draw positions.

Comment: Like that: https://jsfiddle.net/asfga/yjjhqpyL/3/ ? But the outcome is the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is a mess so I needed to clean it up...

First, you have magic numbers spread across HTML javaScript and CSS which is a maintenance nightmare. So I cleaned it up and put all the positioning information into the JS file as that is where it is needed.

The shape was hand coded and with crazy offset that had no meaning. So made the shape an array of points with its origin at center top. (don't need the last point as you were closing the path when not needed).

Then removed jquery as you don't need that and you were not using it properly so effectively slowing your whole page down.

Added divs in code as that is a lot easier than typing all that by hand every time you want to make a change. Stored divs in array so you don't have to query the DOM when you need them later.

You need the canvas position. So I got that via the `getBoundingClientRect` function, so we can adjust the div positions to fit the canvas coordinates.

Then iterate each div and find its top Left with `getBoundingClientRect` subtracted the canvas top left and thus had the canvas coordinates of that div. Then as I needed to know where the background image was I added a function to load that background image and query its dimensions.

**THAT** is when I found out what your problem is.

Your background image is a full sized image with all the pentagons already drawn. It has no relationship the the divs as you don't clip it. You could never line it up unless you had the div coordinates correctly matching the image pentagon positions.

You need to use an image editor and locate each pentagon on the image. Add the locations as an array and draw the shapes at those positions.

I gave up at this point and just added a rectangle over the text in the canvas to show that it is lined up. You will have to workout what you want for the background image. If you want the whole image you will have to find the coordinates for each pentagon by hand. If you just want the first pentagon, clip the image and save one pentagon as an image. Then uncomment the background position rule I commented out and add the magic number offset to the code which will be constant for all divs.

You can find the resulting fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/blindman67/af5L84cv/1/) but it will only be up for a short time as I will remove it once you have had a look.